# no implicit conversion of hash into string

Tags: bundler, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

application.yml file contails configuration as:

```
test:
  STRIPE_API_KEY: sk_test_5USsmmhNqERIQhEQ1ZifD
  STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: pk_test_JE8p4qWciPqYnJZKjlKH8
```

and application.rb contains code as:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.before_configuration do
    env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'application.yml')
    YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
      ENV[key.to_s] = value
    end if File.exists?(env_file)
  end
 end
end
```

I ran into issue when i ran following commands specified by rails when i hit rake:
    bundle config --delete bin
    rake rails:update:bin

Now when i do 'rake' i get the error as - "application.rb:28:in `[]=': no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)" which is line 'ENV[key.to_s] = value' in YAML.load block.
1) First I ran 'bundle config --delete bin'. (why this need to be done).
2) then i commented the before_configuration block in application.rb to prevent above mentioned error and ran cmd "rake rails:update:bin" -  hoping that this command will run without above mentioned error, now the command is succesfull by commenting as mentioned in this point and updated files inside bin dir.
3) then i uncommented the code-and now any rake or rails cmd gives error mentioned above.

Bundler version 1.6.2, rails version 4.1.4, ruby version 2.1.2p95.

Also, before this issue I used to ignore the below message:

Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

```
bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control
```

before doing this the app ran fine. What actually this message says ? clear explanation will be heartly appreciated.

Comment: Could you solve this?  I have the same problem :(

Comment: you need to update the bin inside apps root directory like"rake rails:update:bin"